# Writing a specific query in SQlite

Tags: sqlite, join, relational-division

consider the following schemes

employee (**id**, fname, lname)

department (**dept_no**, dept_name)

project(**proj_no**, proj_name, dept_no)

works_on(**emp_id**, **proj_no**, hours)

the keys are in bold.

I need to find all employees (their names) that are taking part in all of their company's projects.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include details of what you have tried so far, and consequently help us to establish which particular points are giving you problems? Also, can you clarify whether you want all employees taking part in any of the company's projects, or only those employees who are taking part in every single one of the company's projects?

Comment: I don't really know what to try because i'm new to sql, and i got this question as homework. i need to find all employees that are participating every single one of their company's projects

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).